# What are the drawbacks of traditional clustering algorithms?

Tags: clustering

As a newbie, I am interested what the major drawbacks of traditional clustering algorithms are. The purpose is to understand for which class of data or in which scenarios I shouldn't use traditional clustering methods (e.g. K-means)

Comment: They're slow and clustering is inherently subjective.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this great answer for K-means in particular:

[How to understand the drawbacks of K-means](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133656/how-to-understand-the-drawbacks-of-k-means)

My favorite resource for comparing the strengths and weaknesses of clustering algos is from sklearn's docs:

[Comparing different clustering algorithms on toy datasets](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_cluster_comparison.html)